# Adding sqlite3.h inside eclipse

Tags: c++

Hello I am Trying to connect my c++ app to sqlite db.I have downloaded and included sqlite3.dll following this link http://www.forexfactory.com/showthread.php?p=5250053
but still i am getting

## include as unresolved inclusion.

my code

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 #include <sqlite3.h>

 int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_open("test.db", & db);

   string createQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (busid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ipaddr TEXT,    time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW()));";
   sqlite3_stmt *createStmt;
  cout << "Creating Table Statement" << endl;
  sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, createQuery.c_str(), createQuery.size(), &createStmt, NULL);
   cout << "Stepping Table Statement" << endl;
   if (sqlite3_step(createStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Create Table!" << endl;

   string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO items (time, ipaddr) VALUES ('test', '192.168.1.1');"; // WORKS!


   sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt;
   cout << "Creating Insert Statement" << endl;
   sqlite3_prepare(db, insertQuery.c_str(), insertQuery.size(), &insertStmt, NULL);
   cout << "Stepping Insert Statement" << endl;
   if (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Insert Item!" << endl;

cout << "Success!" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `#include <sqlite3.h>` with `#include "sqlite3.h"` (if you have that file in the same folder as your main source file). It may have to do with how the compiler searches for include files. See [this description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) for details on how the MS compiler searches the include paths.

Comment: I m not using ms compiler , I m using mingw gcc compiler I have also tried "sqlite3.h"

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, go to the [SQLite Download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and download the source files. Then put them somewhere in your program's include search path. You may need to change `<sqlite3.h>` to `"sqlite3.h"` since it is not a system include.

For Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives, you need to install the `-dev` package:

> sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev

I had to restart Eclipse to get it to recognize the header file existed.